# item.GetProperty("bodytext").Value Umbraco

Tags: c#, razor, foreach, umbraco

Hello I've had an issue with gathering an object from my Umbraco Blog page specificly cropping it down

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Content.Children.Where("visible==true"))
            {
                var BodyTextToCrop = item.GetProperty("bodytext").Value.ToString();

                <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a><br />

                @Umbraco.Truncate(BodyTextToCrop, 2, true)
            }
```

Comment: What is the issue? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Change your statement to the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible()))
{
    var BodyTextToCrop = item.GetProperty("bodytext").Value.ToString();

    <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a><br />

    @Umbraco.Truncate(BodyTextToCrop, 2, true)
}
```

It looks like your where clause is using the dynamic access of the type and Model.Content could be strongly typed in your case.

Take a look at [querying - MVC](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/querying)
Snippet on the page:

```
//dynamic access
@CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible")

//strongly typed access
@Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible())
```